# How do I correctly release memory in Swift?

Tags: swift

UserManagerViewController is a class that manages user objects (creates/release) for the rest of my view controllers (so that I don't create multiple User objects), I have:

```
var resources = Dictionary<Int, T>()
```

Whenever I need a resource, I do this:

```
let id = data["id"].intValue
self.resources[id] = User(data: data) //Create a User object and set it to the dictionary
```

I have other ViewControllers that "hang on" to this object when it wants to use it:

```
var users = [User]()
users.insert(<The pointer to resources[id]>, atIndex: 99)

//later on...
users.removeAtIndex(99) //this should release its hold
```

Later, when I need to release the final created object, I do this:

```
resources.removeValueForKey(id)
```

Will this method correctly ensure that the `User` instance simply goes away, since both its parents released it?

Comment: Is `User` a class or a struct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the user instance goes away. Swift uses [automatic reference counting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) to manage memory. In your case, when you insert a user into a resource dict, the dict holds a reference to that user. When you later add user into users list, it also holds a reference to the user. It has two references to the same instance, therefore, when you remove user from those data structure, you have no reference to the instance, which means the user instance will be removed.